# best Kubernetes platform for deploying apps while learning

Tags: kubernetes

I want to practice deploying app on real environment while I am learning Kubernetes. Do you know any affordable cloud platform for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I am use this website, with this are possible create a k8s with N nodes ;) this is perfect for learning k8s and make any deployment, each session is for 4h, but this are sufficient.

https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/